# Shoppingassistant does not found on solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java project

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm learning to use appengine with android . There is a sample project on github but seems to be missing a java class. The project is in gihub this link . The other project classes import a class called Shoppingassistant but this class is not in the project. Here is the link android project that communicates with the app engine and the backend project.
Can you help me?

[solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-android-client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-android-client/tree/master/src/com/google/sample/mobileassistant)

[solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java/tree/master/src/com/google/sample/mobileassistant)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions "Developer Guide using Eclipse" on the github pages for those projects.  Shoppingassistant appears to be an endpoints class that is generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the link to the actual tutorial https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

the codes can be downloaded here 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/MobileShoppingAssistant-sample

note that now, the codes for backend is within the client.

It compiles fine and deploy, but I don't have much luck getting it to work. Got stuck at importing data.

hope you have better luck.